# right and left limits and continuity

Tags: limits

Let's say we have a certain function

$$f(x) =     \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      g(x) & x\geq 0 \\
      h(x) & n < x < 0 \\
      i(x) &  x \leq n \\
\end{array} 
\right.$$

for some real number $n$. I have the following questions:

- Can we always say that 
  $$f'(x) =     \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
        g'(x) & x\geq 0 \\
        h'(x) & n < x < 0 \\
        i'(x) &  x \leq n \\
  \end{array} 
  \right.$$
- Let's say we want to test for continuity in $n$. Since $n$ is a right endpoint within $i(x)$, would it be sufficient to find the left limit, which in this case would be $\lim_{x \to n^-} h(x)$?
- Let's say we want to test for continuity in $0$. Since $0$ is a left endpoint within $g(x)$, would it be sufficient to find the right limit, which in this case would be $\lim_{ x \to 0^+} h(x)$?

Comment: The title is not appealing

Comment: I suggest you change the title

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $g(x)$, $h(x)$, and $i(x)$ are continuous. Are those facts given?

Comment: For $x=0$ as well as $x=n$ you need to establish both left and right limits. In each case they need to agree in order to have continuity. That does not imply differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** It's not really nice. I would prefer to say that 
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}g'(x)&x>0\\h'(x)&n<x<0\\i'(x)&x<n\end{cases}$$

and $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}$ and $f'(n)=\lim_{x\to n^-}\frac{i(x)-i(n)}{x-n}$

**2)** If $\lim_{x\to n^-}i(x)=i(n)$ it is sufficient to prove that $\lim_{x\to n^+}h(x)=i(n)$ to have the continuity.

**3)** Same than 2).

Answer (score 0):

- Not completely. Nothing can be said so easily about $f'(0)$ and $f'(n)$. (And of course you are supposing that $g,h,i$ are differentiable in the first place). If you have a nice case where $g(0)=h(0)$, $g'(0)=h'(0)$, $h(n)=i(n)$, and $i'(n)=h'(n)$, then your statement is fine; otheriwse you better check the definition of derivative directly.
- Not unless you know that $i$ is continuous at $n$. On the other hand, if $h,i$ are actually both defined at $x=n$ and are both continuous at $n$, then it suffices to check that $h(n)=i(n)$.
- Same here.

Comment: My book (Adams) says the following: We say $f$ is continuous at a left respectively right endpoint in $c$ in its domain if it's right respectively left continuous there. This leads me to think that what I wrote in the question is right, but it's not (judging from your answer). Why is it incompatible with Adam's statement?